# Should i use lock.lock(): in this method?

Tags: java

I wrote this method whose purpose is to give notice of the fact that a thread is leaving a

specific block of code

A thread stands for a car which is leaving a bridge so other cars can traverse it .

The bridge is accessible to a given number of cars (limited capacity) and it's one way only.

```
public void getout(int diection){
        // release the lock
        semaphore.release();

        try{
            lock.lock(); //access to shared data
            if(direction == Car.NORTH)
                nNordTraversing--; //decreasing traversing threads
            else
                nSudTraversing--;

            bridgeCond.signal(); 

        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
```

My question is: should I use lock.lock(); or it's just nonsense?

thanks in advance

Comment: The requirement for the lock here depends on what the other threads are doing. Are they trying to read/modify the variables that you are decrementing at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

*As we don't have the complete code (what is that semaphore ?), this answer is partly based on guess.*

If your question is related to the increment and decrement operations, then you should know that those operation aren't, in fact, atomic.

So yes, if you have other threads accessing those variables, you need to protect them to ensure that no other thread can read them or worse try to do the same operation, as two parallel increments may result in only one effective.

But as locking has a cost, you may also encapsulate your variable in [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html).

Comment: Your suggestion sounds interesting to me..given my constraints (no use of the Synchronized construct) how should I mend the code in order to use AtomicLong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet and requirement `getout` will not be called by simulatenous thread, only thread which is at the front of the queue, hence the method which is calling `getout` should be synchronized, as not all threads(cars) can be at the front of the queue.

I also think you are using `semaphore` as your guard lock in the calling method.

If in your implementation `getout` is being called by multiple methods then yes you need synchronization and your code is correct.

Comment: nNordTraversing and nSudTraversing are shared data so I need to protect them in order to avoid incoherence. I tried to devise the getout method without resorting to the synchronized construct which I'm not allowed to use...Given that is my code correct?

Comment: yeah then your code is correct, also correctly you are releasing the lock in finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume that nNordTraversing and nSudTraversing are shared data. Since ++ and -- are not atomic operations it is sensefull to lock them, before changing. Otherwise what could happen is the following:

- you read the variable nNordTraversing (e.g. 7)
- another Thread gets scheduled and completes its getout method, it changed the variable (e.g. 7 -- --> 6)
- you are scheduled back, change the variable but on the old data you read (e.g. 7 --> 8)before  the other thread changed it
- the changes of the other thread got over written, the count is not consistent anymore (e.g. its 8 now, but should be 7)

This is called the lost update problem.